# Touchpad stops working after desktop shows up

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, touchpad

I have problem with touch-pad. It is not working correctly. It goes like this. When laptop is booting, right after desktop shows, **I can move mouse with touch-pad for a second**, but when icons shows up, touch-pad does not want to move cursor at all. Even buttons stops work. The same problem with Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu 10.10

I can see "Touchpad" tab in "Mouse" menu, and I can even set "two finger scrolling". I checked in gconf-editor under "desktop->gnome->pheriferals->touchpad" and it's enabled.
Furthermore I checked xinput and it is as it should be:

`SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=11 [slave pointer (2)]`.

I tried to create new master reattach but still nothing...

EDIT: Laptop has `fn + F7` to control touch-pad. Ubuntu shows bobble showing touchpad OFF and touchpad ON. But it does nothing. No matter if it say ON, it still does not work.

Comment: I know this is not an answer and you don't want to hear it but I've suffered a LOT for my touchpad (and multitouch) I've used scripts, bribe, fighting and pain.
Then I've updated to 11.04 and wham: it just worked.

Comment: Just for completeness, please update your question with your laptop's make and model. I've seen touchpad issues with *some* Dell laptops with Synaptics touchpads. If you provide this information someone may be able to dig up a Launchpad bug report with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue on my MacBook Pro when upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04. On the off-chance that it's the same issue, have a look at the [solution I posted on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50534/macbook-pro-5-touchpad-stops-working-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-10-10-to-ubunt).

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious, but does your laptop have a hardware key to toggle the touchpad? It can be located in a different place for each laptop (in my case it's under Fn+F9). What happens when you press this key?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention. Yes it has, Ubuntu shows bobble showing touchpad OFF and touchpad ON. But it does nothing...

Comment: Adam, answers should be answers, not questions. You should only post an answer if it solves the problem. Your question should have been posted in the comments section for the question.

Comment: Well, the suggestion to check the hardware key was my answer, but it looks like it haven't helped anyway.